# How to Close other accordian in angular js

Tags: angularjs

In the below code I am using toggle function which is working properly, but I want to close other accordingly, when one is open

```
 <div class="listing_cat" ng-controller="categoryCtrl">                
             <ul>
              <li class="mob_main_cat" ng-repeat="x in categories" ng-click="toggleCustom($index, $event)" >
                 <span class="cat_left"> {{x.category}}</span>  <span class="cat_right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                 <div class="clearfix"></div>  
                 <ul class="mob_sub_cat" ng-show="custom[$index]">
                   <li class="head">View all in Education</li>
                   <li ng-repeat="x in subcategories"><a href="#">{{x.subcategory}}</a></li>
                  
                 </ul>               
               </li>               
               
             </ul>
            </div>

<script>
$scope.custom = [];     
    $scope.toggleCustom = function(obj,event) { 
      event.stopPropagation(); 
            $scope.custom[obj] = !$scope.custom[obj];                       
        };
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/16884/

Above is my jsfiddle link in which i want to close another when any one is clicked

Comment: depends on whose accordian are you using? I mean bootstrap's, or, other frameworks...(clearly my knowledge is limited...)

Comment: Think hard Dheeraj. You are opening a accordion by changing the value of that accordion (which I assume is false earlier) to true - so, if you want the other accordions to close, what do you think you should do?

Comment: i am just toggling. but i want to close another when one is open

Comment: @Dheeraj Toggling is simply opening something that is closed and closing something that is open. Thus, what do you think you should do if you wish to keep the accordion closed? Look at your toggle code closely.

Comment: You need a reference to the DOM element participating in the accordion. Just call the corresponding api's for open/close on it...

Answer (score 1):

Updated your fiddle with a solution, here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4m92fsqy/

Controller:

```
$scope.toggleCustom = function (obj, event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var temp = $scope.categories[obj].shown
    for (var i=0; i < $scope.categories.length; i++) {
        $scope.categories[i].shown = false;
    }
    $scope.categories[obj].shown = !temp;
};
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="mob_sub_cat" ng-show="categories[$index].shown">
```

Should be simple enough :)